# calculate the VC-dimension

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, algorithms, vc-theory

I have a question about VC-dimension. I have this claim and I need to find out what its VC-dimension is

> $ H\subseteq\{0,1\}^n $ collection of Boolean functions over n

In my opinion the answer should be that the rank of VC-dimension should be 3 or n + 1 but I'm not sure.
By the definition of VC-dimension, the max rank will be equal to the size of the field +1. that means n+1.

I'm not sure why because the functions are binary, it can give a different answer.
If the functions were at base 3, I would get a different answer, and not n + 1?

Comment: [An upper bound on VC dim of finite set $H$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension#Bounds) is $VC(H) \le \log_2 |H|$

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145100/755, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/103482/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).